# Calcular memoria en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, manejo-de-memoria

Buenas, necesito alguna manera de calcular la cantidad de memoria que ha sido necesaria para ejecutar una serie de instrucciones en Python. Algo parecido al `time.clock()`, pero para memoria, alguna ayuda.

Comment: No hace falta que postees en castellano y en ingles. De hecho deberías eliminar la parte en ingles.

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres algo muy detallado podrías usar [**memory_profiler**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) pero si el programa es complejo puede tardar mucho tiempo en darte respuestas. Esto se usa, principalmente, para buscar *memory leaks*.

Si solo te interesa obtener el pico de memoria usado, el mismo creador de **memory_profiler** tiene [esta entrada](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2013/different-ways-to-get-memory-consumption-or-lessons-learned-from-memory_profiler/) en su blog donde llega a esta solución para obtener la memoria usada por el proceso que corre el script Python en cualquier sistema operativo:

```
def memory_usage_psutil():
    # return the memory usage in MB
    import psutil
    import os
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem = process.memory_info().rss / float(2 ** 20)
    return mem
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha sido de gran ayuda

Comment: kikocorreoso como coloco esa funcion en mi codigo?
la pego en mi programa y me sale: none